# How to use subclass of NSManagedObject?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm working on a quite large app on iOS. Up until now, I've been using CoreData like this:

Have a class, that have methods like `-(NSArray*)getAllEntries`, or `-(void)saveEntry:(Entry *)entry`, and `Entry` has a few properties like strings, dictionaries, arrays of other objects that might or might not be saved in CoreData, etc. Mostly, I init `Entry` with its default ctor, and set values to properties by fetching values from the `NSManagedObject` by using `valueForKey:` I get from the CD store.

I started coding like this because at the time I was new to obj-c and I come from a C++/Java background.

Now, I'm working on a new module in the app and want to do everything the obj-c way.

As I understood, if making the `Entry` object a subclass of `NSManagedObject`, I could only init it using `[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entries" inManagedObjectContext:context];`, which means it would be tied to the entity? The thing is, that I might want to for example init that object from the data that I pull from the internet and I might not want to save it to the persistent store. Or, I might want to fetch the object out of the store, edit the values, but not save it to the store. Everything would be fine (probably), but as I understand, if I call the save method on the context which was used to instantiate the object, the object will be saved to the store that I didn't want to be saved.

So now I'm a little confused on how should I continue doing this. Is my old way of doing Core Data Ok, or should I use the subclass of `NSManagedObject` and use some tricks that I don't know of yet? And if the latter, what are those tricks?

Comment: You may be set on working with core data directly, but if you want to make your life easier i suggest checking out https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord

Comment: I highly discourage use of Magic Record.  It may work for the simplest of apps, but if you want any structure at all, it's a mess.

Answer (score 1):

Link answers are discouraged, but you really want to read Apple's extensive documentation on Core Data.  Specifically, google for "Creating and Modifying Custom Managed Objects".

(Currently found at this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/LifeofaManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH16-SW1).)

Comment: Links in answers are not discouraged. Link *only* answer are.